# Why do some applications in Unity start "maximized" but not integrated into the panel?

Tags: unity, panel, maximized

When I start some applications like Gimp or update-manager they start like if they where maximized but they have window decorations, are not integrated into the Unity panel and therefore move towards the screen bottom. 
I also tried to force maximize behaviour via compizconfig-settings-manager but that doesn't change anything.

What can I do to start these applications maximized with integration into the Unity panel?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[gDevilspie](http://code.google.com/p/gdevilspie/) can do that for you!

**What is gDevilspie?**

A user friendly interface to the [Devil's Pie](http://burtonini.com/blog/computers/devilspie) window matching daemon, To create rules easily.

Devil's Pie is a window-matching utility, It can be configured to detect windows as they are created, And match the window to a set of rules. If the window matches the rules, it can perform a series of actions on that window.

**How to install gDevilspie?**

Hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open terminal and run following command:

`sudo apt-get install gdevilspie`

Or search for `gDevilspie` in Software Center and install from there.

**How to use?**

- Once installed, Hit Super key (Windows key) to open Unity dash and search for "gDevilspie" and open it.
- Open "Gimp".
- In gDevilspie click on "add" to add a new rule.
- In "Rule Editor" Click on "Get", Select Gimp window and "Apply".

[image]

- Name this new rule as "Gimp" in top field.
- Under "Matching" tab enable "window_xid" and "application_name"

[image]

- Under "Actions" tab enable "maximize" and click save.

[image]

- On the main window enable the option "Start devilspie daemon automatically at login" and click on "Start". That's it!

[image]

Now whenever you will start "Gimp" it will automatically be maximized. You can add rules for "Update Manager" or any other program in the same way.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the really nice tutorial. I stumbled upon devilspie before but I chose the wrong settings. Nevertheless I'm wondering if it's a Compiz bug because using devilspie is only a workaround.

Comment: I think it's a problem of Gimp not Ubuntu, Because most of the applications work very nicely with Unity.

Comment: I have (now had :-) ) this problem with a lot of applications like update-manager, gnome-system-monitor... So I don't think it's Gimp causing it.