# How to make terminal start maximized?

Tags: command-line, maximized

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to set the terminal to open maximized](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1158/how-to-set-the-terminal-to-open-maximized)

How to make terminal start maximized?

I am looking for a system-wide way, which would work with the CTRL+ALT+T shortcut as well.

Comment: Have you tried [gDevilspie](http://askubuntu.com/q/136734/37006)?

Answer (score 5):

For that you will have to go to **Terminal Menu bar EDIT>>Profile Preferences>> Tick User custom default maximum size**

There you can set the values according to your desktop resolution.

Example , i guess this is what you want.

[image]

Comment: This is not for WINDOW size.

Comment: @jasmines -I meant the maximum value that can be set in the Columns and rows can show.

Comment: But I suppose Krige needs the other solution.

Comment: You may be right , i tried to make it in a simplest possible way.