# Is it possible to start gnome-terminal always in fullscreen mode without menubar?

Tags: gnome, gnome-terminal, fullscreen

Currently I like to start a terminal without mouse moves by

1. `Alt-F2`
2. type in `gnome-term`
3. press `TAB` to get `gnome-terminal` auto-completion
4. `Enter` to start a terminal

However, this approach always provides a terminal that is not in fullscreen mode and has a menubar. Is it possible to change this behavior while **keeping the simple steps** described above?

Update:

There are two related questions [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/142487/430789) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/1158/430789), but they are not as simple as I want: **NO MOUSE MOVE** and **`TAB`** completion. (I'm not sure if Compiz will do these, but I personally think installing Compiz doesn't seem to be a clean and simple solution)

Comment: Gnome terminal has a profile manager built into it. 

If you open gnome terminal, then select Edit -> profile preferences -> General, there is an option that is probably unchecked called "Use Custom Default Terminal Size". 

You can manipulate that to be as close to full screen as you want. Then click close. You should now be able to open and close the terminal any way you choose, and it will start in that size mode.

Comment: @sanimalp what about hiding menubar automatically?

Comment: The menu bar can also be configured to be hidden, it's at Edit -> Preferences -> Show menubar by default in new terminals. You'll still get the window decoration though, you need --fullscreen if you want to start in real full screen mode without any chrome around the terminal area.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`gnome-terminal --full-screen` does what you want, although it is more keypresses than launching `gnome-terminal` and then pressing <kbd>F11</kbd> to enter fullscreen mode.

You might, of course, create a wrapper binary called `gt` or whatever name you prefer:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec gnome-terminal --full-screen "$@"
```

Place it in your `~/bin` directory and give it executable permissions.

Comment: Athough this solution does work, my situation is that I don't have root access... That's why I want a clean solution without installing new packages or changing `bin` directory...

Comment: You don't need root access to create a script under _your personal_ `bin` subdirectory of your home dir which I suggested to you.

Comment: that doesn't work... after export the personal `bin` to path, I can start `gt` from within a `gnome-terminal`, but not the `Alt-F2` run application way...

Comment: Setting `PATH` in `.profile` solved the problem. Thank you very much!

Comment: Your `gt` is not a binary:) It's a text file (a script / a program / an executable but not a binary).

Comment: instead of `gnome-terminal --full-screen`, there also is `gnome-terminal --window --maximize`.

Answer (score 2):

1. Open the `~/.bash_aliases` file with an editor of your choosing.
2. Add this line `alias gnome-terminal='gnome-terminal --full-screen'`
3. Either restart the terminal or type in `source ~/.bash_aliases`
4. Create a custom keyboard shortcut (via Ubuntu GUI, no need for fancy terminal commands) and set the shortcut to <kbd>Ctrl + Alt + T</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

For `CentOS 8 - Stream` I have made size as `95x65` by brute force.

Also, menu hidden with <kbd>Right-click</kbd> **preferences**. And untick the default menu option.

Finally a shortcut added <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>

From **Settings** [Shortcut for CentOS 8 Stream Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7z2d.png)

For adding this shortcut - follow above steps, which is common in CentOS. But implemntation is added in this answer.

[image: Terminal shortcut settings]

Comment: Since this is a Ubuntu only support site do you know for a 100 percent sure that a CentOS answer works?

Comment: you check the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

As for an "anti-mouse" command line operator, why won't you get things yet more automated and put the terminal to your Startup applications?

1. press **Alt+F2** and type: *gnome-session-p*
2. press **Tab** to get: *gnome-session-properties* and press **Enter**;
3. Click **Add** and type in the **Command** field: *gnome-terminal --full-screen*
4. Click **Save**;

From now on each time you boot your Ubuntu you will get the terminal launched in the full screen mode. Whenever you want to reach the desktop behind press `F11` to bring the terminal into a window.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

`xdotool key F11` in .bashrc

Would this work?

Comment it out if you don't want it to start up like that

Comment: Did you try it? This will apply on any virtual terminal and on every nonlogin shell, and will toggle if using the same window (for e.g. using tabs or a screen manager).

Answer (score 0):

You can copy `/usr/share/applications/org.gnome.Terminal.desktop`

To
`/home/<YOUR_USERNAME>/.local/share/applications/org.gnome.Terminal.desktop`

And modify its content, so the terminal will run in fullscreen mode.

```
[Desktop Entry]
...
Exec=gnome-terminal --full-screen
...
```

Now, to run the terminal in full screen, you just need to hit <kbd>super</kbd>, start typing `term...`, and hit enter.