# Ubuntu Gnome Terminal Fullscreen

Tags: command-line, gnome, fullscreen

This has been asked before, but I am not sure that the solution provided (it was a 7 years old post) works.

Basically, I want that every time I open the terminal, it does on fullscreen. I tried writing a command on the profile, but I got a weird glitch.

Anyway. I am open to suggestions. Thanks.

[image]

[image]

Comment: maybe have a lookt at https://askubuntu.com/questions/688584/is-it-possible-to-start-gnome-terminal-always-in-fullscreen-mode-without-menubar

Comment: @masterxilo I did. Which is why in my post I did a reference to a solution from 7 years ago (that post precisely) and the reason why I uploaded these screenshots.

The problem is that when I go with that script on the box (run ... custom command ... gnome-terminal --full-screen) and then I open a new terminal, that one goes crazy and flickers all over the screen. You can try it by yourself if you doubt me. I am certain that you will see exactly what I saw, and it is a disturbing glitch that caught me by surprise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run `terminal` (and specifically `terminal`) full-screen, **just create a window size larger than the display resolution**. This will force `terminal` to start full-screen. To do so, go to Preferences, then the Text Appearance section, and set the Initial Terminal Size to some appropriately large size. I've been running my `terminal` application for years this way.

Alternatively, you could directly edit `/usr/share/applications/org.gnome.Terminal.desktop` and set `Exec=gnome-terminal` to `Exec=gnome-terminal --maximize`, though this will require you to re-edit this file in the event you decide to make the window a different size.

Comment: I like it. I am currently using the shortcut solution, but I think that I would try this one. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution. It may not be the one that I was looking for, but it works.

I went to settings and disabled the shortcut for opening the regular terminal.

Then I created a custom shortcut with the following command: gnome-terminal --full-screen and gave it a keybinding (control + alt + t in my case)

No idea why there isn't that option on preferences, or why there isn't a space on the profiles section to write something like that. But anyway, it worked.

Feel free to leave your comments below, suggestions, opinions, anything. Cheers.

[image]

[image]

[image]